# Array list iterators next and previous not working

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator

I am using next and previous methods in my program. It is Syntactically correct but giving wrong output.

```
import java.util.*;
class Arraylist{
public static void main(String args[]){
    ArrayList<Integer> number = new ArrayList<Integer>(5);      
    int n=0;
    Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
    n=input.nextInt();
    while(n>0){
        number.add(n%10);
        n/=10;
    }
    ListIterator<Integer> itr = number.listIterator(number.size());
    while(itr.hasNext()){
        System.out.print(itr.next() + " ");
    }
    System.out.println("Modifier");
    while(itr.hasPrevious()){
        System.out.print(itr.previous() + " ");
    }
  }
}
```

could help me.

Comment: What output do you have? What did you expect?

Comment: What error or wrong output did you get? What output did you expect? Why? Don't name your class `Arraylist`.

Comment: there is no issue with class name it is fine... and thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [`List#listIterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#listIterator-int-) javadoc (emphasis mine):

> Returns a list iterator over the elements in this list (in proper sequence), **starting at the specified position in the list**.

The issue is here:

```
ListIterator<Integer> itr = number.listIterator(number.size());
                                            //  ^----here---^
```

`number#size` will make the iterator to start at a position after the current size of the list, so calling `itr#hasNext` will return `false`.

To *solve* your problem, just don't pass any argument when calling `List#listIterator`.

Answer (score 1):

You're initializing the `ListIterator` `itr` to after the end of the list, so the first while loop will do nothing since `itr.hasNext()` will return `false` immediately on first iteration.